# How can I solve system of linear equations in SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

Sorry, I am pretty new to sympy and python in general.

I want to solve the following underdetermined linear system of equations:

```
x + y + z = 1 
x + y + 2z = 3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has your research efforts yielded? A websearch appears to offer lots of examples. Please tell me you read the documentation and searched before asking.

Comment: I tried this: solve_linear_system(M, (x, y, z)), where  M = Matrix(((1, 1, 1, - 1), (1, 1, 2, - 3))), It gave me an IndexError.

Comment: You have fewer equations than unknowns here.  You need an SVD solver, not the usual linear solver when you have equal numbers of equations and unknowns.  There's no guarantee of a unique solution.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

SymPy recently got a new Linear system solver: `linsolve` in `sympy.solvers.solveset`, you can use that as follows:

```
In [38]: from sympy import *

In [39]: from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve

In [40]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
```

**List of Equations Form:**

```
In [41]: linsolve([x + y + z - 1, x + y + 2*z - 3 ], (x, y, z))
Out[41]: {(-y - 1, y, 2)}
```

**Augmented Matrix Form:**

```
In [59]: linsolve(Matrix(([1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 3])), (x, y, z))
Out[59]: {(-y - 1, y, 2)}
```

**A*x = b Form**

```
In [59]: M = Matrix(((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 3)))

In [60]: system = A, b = M[:, :-1], M[:, -1]

In [61]: linsolve(system, x, y, z)
Out[61]: {(-y - 1, y, 2)}
```

**Note**: Order of solution corresponds the order of given symbols.

Comment: It should be noted, that linsolve is not yet available in any release. Currently accessible only through the development version.

Comment: I am using sympy 0.7.6, First I could not get linsolve so used solve, Second The Augmented matrix and Ax = b form gives EMPTY LIST [  ] answer, only first method gives solution as like above, how can we fix this?

Comment: Sidenote: You can get the results out of the `FiniteSet` wrapper using `.args[0]`.

Answer (score 20):

```py
import sympy as sp
x, y, z = sp.symbols('x, y, z')
eq1 = sp.Eq(x + y + z, 1)             # x + y + z  = 1
eq2 = sp.Eq(x + y + 2 * z, 3)         # x + y + 2z = 3
ans = sp.solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y, z))
```

this is similar to @PaulDong answer with some minor changes

1. its a good practice getting used to not using `import *` (numpy has many similar functions)
2. defining equations with `sp.Eq()` results in cleaner code later on

Comment: Adding further explanation would help readers understand why your answer is better than the others and enable them to vote for you. Expand your answer using  the [edit] function.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the great answers given by @AMiT Kumar and @Scott, SymPy 1.0 has added even further functionalities. For the underdetermined linear system of equations, I tried below and get it to work without going deeper into `sympy.solvers.solveset`. That being said, do go there if curiosity leads you.

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
eq1 = x + y + z
eq2 = x + y + 2*z
solve([eq1-1, eq2-3], (x, y,z))
```

That gives me `{z: 2, x: -y - 1}`. 
Again, great package, SymPy developers!

Answer (score 5):

Another example on matrix linear system equations, lets assume we are solving for this system:

[image]

In `SymPy` we could do something like:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
... sy.init_printing()

>>> a, b, c, d = sy.symbols('a b c d')
... A = sy.Matrix([[a-b, b+c],[3*d + c, 2*a - 4*d]])
... A

⎡ a - b     b + c  ⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎣c + 3⋅d  2⋅a - 4⋅d⎦


>>> B = sy.Matrix([[8, 1],[7, 6]])
... B

⎡8  1⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣7  6⎦


>>> A - B

⎡ a - b - 8     b + c - 1  ⎤
⎢                          ⎥
⎣c + 3⋅d - 7  2⋅a - 4⋅d - 6⎦


>>> sy.solve(A - B, (a, b, c, d))
{a: 5, b: -3, c: 4, d: 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve in matrix form `Ax=b` (in this case an underdetermined system but we can use [`solve_linear_system`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve_linear_system)):

```
from sympy import Matrix, solve_linear_system

x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
A = Matrix(( (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 3) ))
solve_linear_system(A, x, y, z)

{x: -y - 1, z: 2}
```

Or rewrite as (my editing, not sympy):

```
[x]=  [-1]   [-1]
[y]= y[1]  + [0]
[z]=  [0]    [2]
```

In the case of a square `A` we could define `b` and use `A.LUsolve(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let the system be as follows

```
y + z -2w = -3 
x + 2y -z = 2
2x + 4y +z - 3w = -2
x - 4y -7z -w = -19
```

To get a solution set, we can use the following code

```
import sympy as sp
sp.linsolve(sp.Matrix([
    [0, 1, 1, -2, -3],
    [1, 2, -1, 0, 2],
    [2, 4, 1, -3, -2],
    [1, 4, -7, -1, -19]
]))
```

which will yield the following output

```
{(-21/5,26/5,21/5,31/5)}
```