# Solving a system of linear equations using SymPy when more than one symbol appears in matrix coefficients

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve an electrical pi-network that looks like this:

```
   un             uf
o-->-----[zb]------<---o
+     |         |      +
pn   [yn]      [yf]    pf
-     |         |      -
o----------------------o
```

I do the nodal analysis and get an equivalent system of equations that look like this for two unique sets of p's and u's.

```
un1, un2, uf1, uf2, pn1, pn2, pf1, pf2, yn, yf, zp = symbols('un1 un2 uf1 uf2 pn1 pn2 pf1 pf2 yn yf zp')
eqns=[un1 -pn1*(yn + 1/zp) - pf1*(-1/zp), 
      uf1 - pn1*(-1/zp) + pf1*(yf+1/zp),
      un2 - pn2*(yn + 1/zp) - pf2*(-1/zp),
      uf2 - pn2*(-1/zp) - pf2*(yf + 1/zp)]
```

I want to solve for yn, zp and yf in terms of the u and p terms since the u and p terms are given. (By u and p I mean un1, un2, uf1, uf2, pn1, pn2, pf1, pf2).

I found the response at the bottom and tried to use the linsolve function, but I get the null set:

```
In: linsolve(eqns, [yn, yf, zp])
Out: EmytySet()
```

If I put in dummy coefficients for the equations, than it behaves as expected

```
In: Y11, Y12, Y21, Y22 = symbols('Y11, Y12, Y21, Y22')
In: eqns_test = [un1 -pn1*Y11 - pf1*Y12, 
                 uf1 - pn1*Y21 - pf1*Y22,
                 un2 - pn2*Y11 - pf2*Y12,
                 uf2 - pn2*Y21 - pf2*Y22]
In: linsolve(eqns_test, Y11, Y12, Y21, Y22)
Out:{((pf1*un2 - pf2*un1)/(pf1*pn2 - pf2*pn1), (-pn1*un2 + pn2*un1)/(pf1*pn2 - pf2*pn1), (pf1*uf2 - pf2*uf1)/(pf1*pn2 - pf2*pn1), (-pn1*uf2 + pn2*uf1)/(pf1*pn2 - pf2*pn1))}
```

How should I solve this system of equations?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547657/how-can-i-solve-system-of-linear-equations-in-sympy#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547657/how-can-i-solve-system-of-linear-equations-in-sympy#_=_)

Comment: The system of equations you are trying to solve in not linear, whereas `linsolve` solves a system of N linear equations with M variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is nonlinear so you need to use nonlinsolve() solver from sympy.

```
printing.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
un1, un2, uf1, uf2, pn1, pn2, pf1, pf2, yn, yf, zp = symbols('un1 un2 uf1 uf2 pn1 pn2 pf1 pf2 yn yf zp')
eqns=[un1 -pn1*(yn + 1/zp) - pf1*(-1/zp), 
    uf1 - pn1*(-1/zp) + pf1*(yf+1/zp),
    un2 - pn2*(yn + 1/zp) - pf2*(-1/zp),
    uf2 - pn2*(-1/zp) - pf2*(yf + 1/zp)]
sol=nonlinsolve(eqns, [yn, yf, zp])
pprint(sol)
```

Output:

```
⎧⎛pf₁⋅un₂ - pf₂⋅un₁ - pn₁⋅un₂ + pn₂⋅un₁  -(uf₁⋅(pf₁⋅pn₂ - pf₂⋅pn₁) + (pf₁ + pn
⎨⎜─────────────────────────────────────, ─────────────────────────────────────
⎩⎝          pf₁⋅pn₂ - pf₂⋅pn₁                               pf₁⋅(pf₁⋅pn₂ - pf₂

₁)⋅(pn₁⋅un₂ - pn₂⋅un₁))   pf₁⋅pn₂ - pf₂⋅pn₁⎞⎫
────────────────────────, ─────────────────⎟⎬
⋅pn₁)                     pn₁⋅un₂ - pn₂⋅un₁⎠⎭
​
```

[image]