# How to solve a system with 3 unknowns and 2 equations depending on a parameter in python

Tags: python, solver

I have these two equation below. I want to solve this system parametrically.

```
1.182 * a == 4.0 * b + 4.0

a^2 == 4.0 * b * c + 4.0
```

It is possible to solve it via MATLAB with the function below. It solves b and c with respect to a.

```
  sol = solve(prob,[b,c]);
```

result:

```
b: 0.2956 * a - 1.0 

c: (5.629e+14 * a^2 - 2.252e+15) / (6.656e+14 * a - 2.252e+15)
```

How can I get the same result in python. I couldn't find a similar function.

Comment: You can use SymPy like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547657/how-can-i-solve-system-of-linear-equations-in-sympy

Answer (score 2):

Upon running

```
from sympy import Eq, solve, symbols

a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')
soln = solve((Eq(1.182 * a, 4.0 * b + 4.0),
              Eq(a ** 2, 4.0 * b * c + 4.0)),
             (b, c))
print('\n'.join(sorted(map(str, soln[0]))))
```

we obtain:

```
0.2955*a - 1.0
500.0*(a - 2.0) * (a + 2.0) / (591.0*a - 2000.0)
```